# Rewrite URL SEO

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, seo

My site has a url like this

```
http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?page=doctors&docid=99
```

Using SEO rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^doctors/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ index.php?page=doctors&docid=$1 [L]
```

I get

```
www.mydomain.com/doctors/13/Dr.-John-Smith.html
```

But I want a more friendly url like this

```
www.mydomain.com/Dr.-John-Smith.html
```

How can I achive this url.

Comment: Try these resources: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: could you provide a better solution..??

Answer (score 0):

REWRITING QUERY STRINGS

If you are hired to recreate an existing website from scratch, you might use URL rewriting to redirect the 20 most popular URLs on the old website to the locations on the new website. This could involve redirecting things like prod.php?id=20 to products/great-product/2342, which itself gets redirected to the actual product page.

Apache’s RewriteRule applies only to the path in the URL, not to parameters like id=20. To do this type of rewriting, you will need to refer to the Apache environment variable %`{QUERY_STRING}`. This can be accomplished like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}           ^id=20$                   
RewriteRule   ^prod.php$             ^products/great-product/2342$      [L,R=301]
RewriteRule   ^products/(.*)/([0-9]+)$  ^productview.php?id=$1             [L]
```

In this example, the first RewriteRule triggers a permanent redirect from the old website’s URL to the new website’s URL. The second rule rewrites the new URL to the actual PHP page that displays the product.

I hope this helps, find out a lot more about rewrites here:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

It's laid out in a pretty straight forward fashion. Hope that helps, please let me know if you have any other questions. Thank you.

Comment: ok, but if the url is www.mydomain.com/doctors/13/Dr.-John-Smith.html to convert in  www.mydomain.com/Dr.John-Smith.html what i need to do